# Reduce the thickness of a svg image (arrow)

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to reduce the thickness of an arrow SVG image.I tried with stroke="grey" stroke-width="-10".When I change the value of stroke-width it's only increasing the thickness without reducing.

```html
<svg fill="#808080" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M8.59 16.34l4.58-4.59-4.58-4.59L10 5.75l6 6-6 6z" stroke="grey" stroke-width="-10"/>
    <path d="M0-.25h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I think that "0" is the mininum possible stroke-width. You could try editing the shape in Inkscape.

Comment: The size of the image is not determined by the stroke...but rather the path.

Comment: simply remove the stroke, that's it

Answer (score 0):

The best way to demonstrate this is with a gif.
[image]

The shape has a mininum width, and increasing that width will result in a thicker shape.

But, as Paulie_D said:

> The size of the image is not determined by the stroke...but rather the
>   path

The only way to actually *decrease* the width is to modify the path in a vector editor such as [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org). Clicking the second tool on the left (or pressing F2) will show boxes around the corners. The boxes can be dragged around to make the shape thinner.